# C# LINQ to Entities Select String confusion NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, notsupportedexception

Hi I have this LINQ and in my DB there is a row ind kalk table with MedID="---" and KalkID="00057" and if i hard code them in everything works but if i get them from my stVar which is a String[] i get a NotSupportedException:

```
ObjectSet<Kalk> kalks = ke.Kalks;  
            var query =  
               from kalk in kalks  
               where kalk.MedID.Equals(stVar[0])//"---"  
                  && kalk.KalkID.Equals(stVar[1])//"00057"  
               select new  
               {  
                   MedID = kalk.MedID,  
                   KalkID = kalk.KalkID,  
                   Navn = kalk.Navn,  
                   ValutaID = kalk.ValutaID,  
                   Sprog = kalk.Sprog,  
                   Dato = kalk.Dato,  
                   SidstRettet = kalk.SidstRettet,  
                   SidstRettetAf = kalk.SidstRettetAf,  
                   Afrunding = kalk.Afrunding,  
                   Kurs = kalk.Kurs,  
                   id = kalk.id  
               };  
            foreach (var item in query)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show(item.MedID + item.Navn);  
            }
```

Comment: Are MedID and KalkID string types? If not try `kalk.MedID.ToString().Equals(strVar[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ObjectSet<Kalk> kalks = ke.Kalks;

// Linq-to-SQL (or EF or whichever LINQ provider you use) probably doesn't
// support array indexers, so put your strings in variables beforehand
var medID = stVar[0];
var kalkID = stVar[1];

var query =
    from kalk in kalks
    where kalk.MedID.Equals(medID) //"---"
       && kalk.KalkID.Equals(kalkID) //"00057"
    select new
    {
        MedID = kalk.MedID,
        KalkID = kalk.KalkID,
        Navn = kalk.Navn,
        ValutaID = kalk.ValutaID,
        Sprog = kalk.Sprog,
        Dato = kalk.Dato,
        SidstRettet = kalk.SidstRettet,
        SidstRettetAf = kalk.SidstRettetAf,
        Afrunding = kalk.Afrunding,
        Kurs = kalk.Kurs,
        id = kalk.id
    };
 foreach (var item in query)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(item.MedID + item.Navn);
 }
```